# relations problem :recurrence relation

Tags: relations

need help with the following question:

let $R$ be a binary relation.

We will define a series of relations $R_1,R_2,R_3\dots$ so that:

$R_0 = R$

$R_{i+1} = R_i\cup\{\langle x,y\rangle :\exists y(xR_iy\wedge yR_iz)\}$

we need to prove that $\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}R_i$ is transitive 
thank you:)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at both links [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and for formatting [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). There is no question posed.

Comment: just edited it - could you take a look again?

Answer (score 0):

Denote $S=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}R_i$.

First observe that $i\leq j\implies R_i\subseteq R_j\subseteq S$.

You can formally prove that by induction.

Let $xSy$ and $ySz$.

Then $xR_iy$ and $yR_jz$ for nonnegative integers $i,j$.

Then if $k=\max(i,j)$ we have $xR_ky\wedge yR_kz$ hence $xR_{k+1}z$.

Then $xSz$ because $R_{k+1}\subseteq S$.

Comment: thank you:)

is j=i+1 ?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: ok, cant you just say that if k = max(i,J) then Ri ⊆ Rk and Rj ⊆ Rk then xRky ∧ yRkz and xRk+1z, then because  Rk+1 ⊆ S then S is transitive without induction?

Comment: Yes you can. I do not use any induction in my answer. The phrase "you can prove that by induction" is only referring to a formal proof of $R_i\subseteq R_j$ if $i <j$. Not to what follows.